# How to compress multiple folders into multiple zip files

Tags: bash, zip

My folder structure is:

YEAR - MONTH - DAY - SUBFOLDERS

I want to compress each subfolder in the [DAY] directories. The solution from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452384/how-to-compress-multiple-folders-each-into-its-own-zip-archive) which is:

```
for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

works fine as long as I'm doing it from a [DAY] folder. But if I change it to:

```
for i in */*/; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

and run from a [MONTH] folder it still works, but the problem is that the .zip now contains an additional parent folder for each additional '/*' in the command when I unpack.

How can I run the command from a [YEAR] folder with '/* /* /*' while making sure that the .zip only contains the lowest level subfolder when I unpack?

Comment: How is this related to Apple?  This is probably a better fit on [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Allan Shell scripting is on-topic here :-)

Comment: True, but there are subtle differences in commands if this is a Linux box.  Just look at `grep`.  That's why I didn't flag to close but asked for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can combine two loops to accomplish this

```
cd YEAR
for month in */; do
    (cd "$month";  for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done)
done
```

PS: If MONTH folders can be empty you need to check for this in the inner loop.

Comment: But...+1 anyway...'cause it's a damm good answer.